# How to stop or restrict Web attack on apache? and how to know which type of web attack it is?

Tags: antivirus, apache

Today Symantec antivirus has blocked web attack which is as follows

```
Web Attack: Malicious Scan Request attack blocked. Traffic has been blocked for this application: \DEVICE\HARDDISKVOLUME4\APACHE2.2\BIN\HTTPD.EXE

Web Attack: Malicious Scan Request
```

what is the hacker trying to do with my apache httpd.exe file? can anyone elaborate?

Comment: The information You're giving is insufficient, but there's a good chance that is normal background noise, port- or vulnerability scans on your host. Nothing to worry about if your server is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

The information you are giving is insufficient, however you may Harden your Server, by filtering ports or closing the ports that are not in use. Additionally, you may add a Network Based Intrusion Detection System to get information regarding any intrusion occurs in your network.
Also, you may update the services running on ports since, using the older versions of services lead to un-authorized access to the Server by exploiting their vulnerability or a Denial of Service attack might be possible in order to crash your server.